# jquery pagination datable serializeArray only capture first 10 result

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

What I want to do is capture all the entries of my table, but with serializeArray I can only capture the first 10 that are pagination enabled, but I also want to capture the rest of the data

```
table_pedido = $("#view_pedido_nuevo").DataTable({
      processing: true,
      destroy: true,
      paging: true,
      lengthChange: true,
      searching: true,
      ordering: true,
      info: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      scrollX: true,
      scrollY: true,
      data: data,
      language: espanol,
      columns: [
        { data: "CODARTICULO", className: "text-center" },
        { data: "DESCRIPCION", className: "text-center" },
        {
          data: "CODARTICULO",
          render: function (data, type, datos, row) {
            return `<input type="number" value="0" class="form-control">
            <input type="text" value="${datos.CODARTICULO}" name="input_name_cod[]" class="form-control">
            <input type="text" value="${datos.DESCRIPCION}" name="input_name_des[]" class="form-control">
            `;
          },
        },
      ],
    });
```

button:

```
$("#btn_transferencia_grupo_enviar").on("click", function () {
let cod_articulo = $(
  "#view_pedido_nuevo tbody tr :input[name='input_name_cod[]']"
).serializeArray()});
```

consolo.log

```
    (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13532'}
1: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13533'}
2: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13534'}
3: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13537'}
4: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13538'}
5: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13539'}
6: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13541'}
7: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13543'}
8: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13544'}
9: {name: 'input_name_cod[]', value: '13545'}
```

But I'm missing the data on page 2 and 3

Comment: I see a variable called **data**, I'm guessing that holds your table's data. Have you tried filtering through that instead?

Comment: Of course, that brings me the data, that is, the databable fills it well, what I cannot do is obtain the information of page 2 and 3, only the first 10 of page 1

Comment: Which `DataTable` plugin are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, then get the inputs you wish from this `tableData` perhaps?

`var tableData = $("#view_pedido_nuevo").DataTable().rows().data().toArray();`

Example:

`const data = $("#view_pedido_nuevo").DataTable().rows().nodes().map((e) => $(e).find('input[name="input_name_cod[]"]').serializeArray());`

Comment: Assumptions made on the plugin in use here...

Comment: Only one query helped me how can I transform it to how I put the example above in the consolelog is that I get array array   r(28) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), context: Array(1), selector: {…}, tables: ƒ, table: ƒ, draw: ƒ, …]